# Run postgres operator with statement timeout airflow dag

Tags: postgresql, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, postgres-operator

so i've been trying to run 2 postgres operator on my DAG and looks like this:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'local',
}

log = logging.getLogger(_name_)

TEMP_SETTLEMENT ="""
set statement_timeout to 0;
select function_a();
"""

VACUM_SETTLEMENT="""
vacuum (verbose, analyze) test_table;
"""

try:
    with DAG(
        dag_id='temp-test',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=none,
        start_date=datetime(2021, 10, 1),
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=False
    ) as dag:

        pg = PostgresOperator(
            task_id="data",
            postgres_conn_id="connection_1",
            database="DB_test",
            autocommit=True,
            sql=TEMP_SETTLEMENT,
        )

        vacum = PostgresOperator(
            task_id="vacum",
            postgres_conn_id="connection_1",
            database="DB_test",
            autocommit=True,
            sql=VACUM_SETTLEMENT,    )

        pg >> vacum 

except ImportError as e:
    log.warning("Could not import DAGs: %s", str(e))
```

i keep getting the statement timeout when i try to run the temp_settlement, is there any way to keep the statement_timeout=0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Note that `PostgresOperator` is deprecated. It is best to migrate to [`apache-airflow-providers-common-sql`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-common-sql/)
Then use:

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
...,
conn_id='postgres_default', # specify the Postgres conn_id 
hook_params={'options': '-c statement_timeout=3000ms'}
)
```

If for some reason you are not able to use `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` then:

For [`apache-airflow-providers-postgres>=5.5.2`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/5.5.2/)
you can do:

```
PostgresOperator(
...,
hook_params={'options': '-c statement_timeout=3000ms'}
)
```

For [`apache-airflow-providers-postgres>=4.1.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/)
you can do:

```
PostgresOperator(
...,
runtime_parameters={'statement_timeout': '3000ms'},
)
```

This capability was added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/21551) that solved [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/21486).

**Original Answer:**

You didn't mention it by from your description I assume that the timeout comes from Postgres and not from Airflow.

For the moment the `PostgresOperator` does not allow to override the hook/connection settings.
To solve your issue you will need to edit `connection_1` in the extra field as explained in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/connections/postgres.html#configuring-the-connection) you will need to add `statement_timeout`:

```
{'statement_timeout': '3600s'}
```

I opened https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/21486 as a followup feature request to allow setting `statement_timeout` directly from the operator.

Comment: Sorry my bad @Elad, my timeout comes from the postgres. the function takes long time depends on how many data is coming. if i tried to use my code, the temp will execute 2 different state.

Comment: @YohanesLim do you will need to set this parameter in the connection

Comment: is there any way that i can set this temporary ? if i go to postgres and do the exact query, it will count as 1 state and will run. is there any way to use this using airflow ?

Comment: You can create a custom MyPostgresHook and custom MyPostgresOperator that will have the functionality you want

Comment: Thanks for the information @Elad ! do you know where to find a good example for this? i've been searching yet i got very low reference about this.

Comment: @YohanesLim Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. will try to see this new feature. @Elad